# How to insert data at pull queue using rest API(php code) at GAE

Tags: php, python, api, rest, google-app-engine

How to insert data at pull queue using rest API(php code) at GAE

I am following below link
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest/tasks/insert
My code is

```
$target_url = 'https://content.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta2/projects/s~<projectname>/taskqueues/<task_queue_name>/tasks?key=<Server key >&alt=json';
$post = array('queueName' => '<task_queue_name>', 'payloadBase64'=>'aGVsbG8=');
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $post);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($server_output);
curl_close ($ch);
```

But I can't insert data at pull queue , please help me

I also configure queue.yaml and set here **ACL**

Result

> { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required",
>   "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location":
>   "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you other ticket, give this a whirl:

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-pull-queue

Removes the need for the REST API from PHP on App Engine.

Tom

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Sure thing - open source!

Comment: At documentation there is a note i.e

ALPHA This library is in the very early stages of development. Do not use it in production. It will change.

So I am worried about it. 
Although this library working successfully

Comment: Well it's up to you. The documentation is correct, the library is in alpha. I will develop it, add features, make it more robust over time.

Comment: If i use this code , in future any fatal error may occurred ??  I use this code at production. So please tell me..

Comment: I have released v0.0.1-alpha for you. That code will never change now.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - You don't need to manually make HTTP calls with CURL, you should use the [API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started) that is provided by Google since it takes care of all the auth stuff for you.

The type of authorization used with the Task Queue API (as well as most Google Cloud Platform APIs) is OAuth2. This requires sending an 'Authorization: Bearer ' header with the request, and not sending a server key along with the query string as you are doing. From the same doc you linked to, you can use the 'Try it!' section to see what the full HTTP request looks like with OAuth2.

However, the recommended way to interact with Google APIs is to use the provided [API Client Library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started) which takes care of all of the authorization stuff for you. If you want to know the full details you can read about it at [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google./identity/protocols/OAuth2) which contains examples for different types of apps using PHP and raw HTTP.

The following untested snippet shows how inserting a task with the client library using a service account with OAuth2 might look like:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue']);
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);  // This is your service account JSON key you need to export from the Developers Console

$service = new Google_Service_Taskqueue($client);
$results = $service->insert(opts...)
```